# How to get the socket's specific error reason when POLLERR happens?

Tags: sockets, epoll

When `POLLERR` comes up after polling, how can I determine the specific error reason?

Comment: Think this question might need some more context Vincent. Perhaps add some tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `getsockopt()` with the option `SO_ERROR`.